# Regular Expression in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a regular expression having the following requirements.

1.Minimum 8 character's.
2.at least letter.
3.at least number .
4.at least special character.

i tried this one but not working for me.

```
(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Comment: `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])` means that you need at least one upper-case letter and at least one lower-case letter. Merge the two character classes to only `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` or use the case-insensitive flag `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^(?=.{8})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

Note that:

- For checking at least 8 characters, you can leave out the comma and `$` (both), as it is not necessary to look any further when 8 characters have been found.
- For checking special characters (like any other character class), you don't need to add the `+`: when one is found, the condition has been fulfilled.
- No distinction should be made (in your case) between lower case and upper case, so those tests should be merged.
- As you have no condition about points or newlines, that test should be removed (`(?![.\n])`).
- You probably want the caret at the very start, not in the first group: you'll want all characters in the input to match or none.